# react-admin: `data` is undefined in onSuccess() on <Edit> component

Tags: react-admin

I'm trying to follow the example from https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#onsuccess.
I'd like to notify users with the record title on update.

```
    const onSuccess = ({ data }) => {
        console.log(data) // output: undefined
        notify(`Changes to post "${data.title}" saved`)
        redirect('/posts');
        refresh();
    };
```

JS always complains that `undefined` does not have a `title` property.

According to the docs, `data` comes from the response of `dataProvider.update()`

> The onSuccess function receives the response from the dataProvider call (dataProvider.create() or dataProvider.update())...

But, from what I tested, `onSuccess()` is called right away on submit, and `dataProvider.update()` is called when the toast message disappears, so `onSuccess()` does not receive the result of the Promise returned by `dataProvider.update()`.

Is there something I'm missing in the example?

#### Additional informations

I'm using `react-admin` v3.11.1 and Chrome 87.0.4280.88
The record is updated correctly if I remove `onSuccess()` from the  Component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in `Edit` context you have to set `undoable={false}` to the `Edit` component to prevent optimistic response that does not wait for the request response.

```js
<Edit
  {...props}
  onSuccess={onSuccess}
  undoable={false}
>
    ...
</Edit>
```

Ref: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#undoable

Comment: I do want to keep the option to undo. Both are not compatible?

Comment: Unfortunately I think not. I might be wrong so I suggest you to ask directly on the github repository with a minimal reproducible example so the owner can answer properly.